# Trying to use D3 with React to create a bar chart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to render a simple bar chart using D3 on my web application, which uses React for its front end.

I'm new to D3 and am under a major time crunch to get a bar chart showing up on my web page, so I figured the easiest thing for me to do would be to find a jsfiddle that renders a simple bar chart using D3 
(http://jsfiddle.net/tommy351/P4Z75/)
and copy and paste the code into my dashboard.tsx file.

Note: The reason I chose D3 is because other, easier-to-use charting libraries that integrate more smoothly with React (i.e. recharts, react-d3) don't have TypeScript definition files.

So, here's a snippet of my dashboard.tsx file:

```
         import * as React from "react";
         import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
         import * as D3 from "d3";

         var data = [4, 5, 10, 16, 23, 35];
         var width = 500;
         var barHeight = 20;

         var x = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
             .range([0, width]);

        var chart = d3.select('#chart')
             .attr('width', width)
             .attr('height', barHeight * data.length);

        var bar = chart.selectAll('g')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
              return 'translate(0,' + barHeight * i + ')';
             });

       bar.append('rect')
             .attr('width', x)
             .attr('height', barHeight - 1);

       bar.append('text')
              .attr('x', function (d) {
                return x(d) - 3;
               })
              .attr('y', barHeight / 2)
              .attr('dy', '.35em')
              .text(function (d) {
                return d;
               });
      render() {
         return ( <div>
            <svg id="chart"></svg>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

There errors I get in my console are:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartjs is not defined
   at Object.map../af (vendorReact.js:26748)
   at __webpack_require__ (vendorReact.js:53)
   at Object.<anonymous> (vendorReact.js:107)
   at __webpack_require__ (vendorReact.js:53)
   at vendorReact.js:96
   at vendorReact.js:99

 Dashboard.js:17482 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of 
    undefined
   at Object.<anonymous> (Dashboard.js:17482)
   at Object.<anonymous> (Dashboard.js:17721)
   at Object.163 (Dashboard.js:17723)
   at __webpack_require__ (vendorReact.js:53)
   at Object.0 (Dashboard.js:17)
   at __webpack_require__ (vendorReact.js:53)
   at webpackJsonpCallback (vendorReact.js:24)
   at Dashboard.js:1
```

I've tried the same thing with a number of jsfiddles and get similar errors in my console and can't get the charts to render. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: you could just get away by using the javascript instead of typescript, your script doesn't even reflect what typescript features.

Comment: It'd be much easier/more comfortable for me to use something like recharts (React charts), but recharts doesn't have a TypeScript definition file. I just showed you a small snippet of my dashboard.tsx file, it actually is using TypeScript libraries/features, they're just not reflected in the snippet I showed you.

Comment: it doesn't matter, just use what you feel comfortable with. typescript is a subset of javascript. you can use javascript in typescript.

Comment: I am using JavaScript in my TypeScript, I copied all that code from that jsFiddle's JavaScript. The issue is that all external JavaScript libraries require TypeScript definitions files

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your first error but the second one could be due to the d3 version. If you are importing the latest version of d3 then `var x = d3.scale.linear()` needs to be `var x = d3.scaleLinear()`. See the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale) for more information.

Note: I would normally have just put this as a comment as it doesn't answer the whole question by I am 1 reputation point shy of being able to comment sorry.

Comment: I changed that line to `var x = d3.scaleLinear()` but now it's giving me an error

Comment: I get an error in my IDE that says `property 'scaleLinear' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'`

Comment: oh wait, you've imported `d3` as `D3` - `import * as D3 from "d3";`. The capital makes a difference. See if that works

Comment: you're importing d3 as `D3` but trying to call it using `d3`. Try changing your import statement to `import * as d3 from "d3";` and leave the rest of your code the same.

Comment: I just changed it to that and I'm still running into the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143226/discussion-between-michael-hall-and-aliciaguerra).